# The dft magnitudes aren't linear with dft point number in my matlab code

Tags: matlab, fft, dft

- Dft magnitudes conclusion from Richard Lyons [Understanding digital signal processing]
  [image: expression about Dft magnitudes]
- my verification code

```
pointno_iteration_times = 5;
for i = 0:1:pointno_iteration_times
    log2_dft_point_num = 7+i;
    dft_point_no = 2^log2_dft_point_num;
    fsDataIn = 1e6;
    freqInput = 5e4;
    deltaT = 1/fsDataIn;
    Length = dft_point_no*deltaT*6;
    t = 0:deltaT:Length;
    sine_dataIn=sin(2*pi*freqInput*t);
    
    [fft_result, real_part, imag_part] = FFT_spectrum_generate(sine_dataIn,dft_point_no);
    target_bin = round(freqInput*dft_point_no/fsDataIn);
    p1_target_bin(i+1) = fft_result(target_bin);
    x_label(i+1) = 2^log2_dft_point_num;
end
figure('name','fft scan result');
subplot(1,1,1);
plot(x_label,p1_target_bin);
xlabel('dft point number');
ylabel('FFT result');
title('sine amplitude vs FFT result');

function [P, real_part, imag_part] = FFT_spectrum_generate(x,N)
   Y=fft(x,N);
   P1=abs(Y/N); 

   P = P1(1:N/2+1); 
   P(2:end-1) = 2*P(2:end-1); 
   real_part = real(Y);
   imag_part = imag(Y);
end
```

- matlab result
  [image: dft point number vs fft result]
- Question: Why can't I get a linear dft result? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems

1. The text clearly states "with an integral number of cycles over N
   input samples". That's not the case in your code, so you have
   spectral leakage. In other words `target_bin` needs to be an integer
   without rounding.
2. Matlab starts indexing at 1, not at 0 so you need to get the result from `fft_result(target_bin+1);` not `fft_result(target_bin);`

Code

```
pointno_iteration_times = 5;
for i = 0:1:pointno_iteration_times
    log2_dft_point_num = 7+i;
    dft_point_no = 2^log2_dft_point_num;
    fsDataIn = 1e6;
    freqInput = 5e4;
    deltaT = 1/fsDataIn;
    Length = dft_point_no*deltaT*6;
    t = 0:deltaT:Length;
    target_bin = round(freqInput*dft_point_no/fsDataIn);
    % adjust frequency to have an integer number of cycles
    freqInput  = target_bin*fsDataIn/dft_point_no;
    sine_dataIn=sin(2*pi*freqInput*t);
    
    [fft_result, real_part, imag_part] = FFT_spectrum_generate(sine_dataIn,dft_point_no);
    % Matlab needs an indexing offset of 1
    p1_target_bin(i+1) = fft_result(target_bin+1);
    x_label(i+1) = 2^log2_dft_point_num;
end
figure('name','fft scan result');
subplot(1,1,1);
plot(x_label,p1_target_bin);
xlabel('dft point number');
ylabel('FFT result');
title('sine amplitude vs FFT result');

function [P, real_part, imag_part] = FFT_spectrum_generate(x,N)
   Y=fft(x,N);
   P1=abs(Y/N); 

   P = P1(1:N/2+1); 
   P(2:end-1) = 2*P(2:end-1); 
   real_part = real(Y);
   imag_part = imag(Y);
 
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Problem solved. I could hardly notice these details on my own.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the time to decipher your code. Try the following to verify the above Eq. (3-17):

```
clear, clc
N = 24 % Number of input samples
n = 0:N-1; 
Fs = 8000; % Sample rate in Hz
ts = 1/Fs;
Peak_Amp = 3 % Sine wave's peak amplitude
x = Peak_Amp*sin(2*pi*1000*n*ts);
% This command should have an asterisk between
the letter 'p' and the letter 's'.]
figure(1), clf
plot(n, x,':ks','markersize',6)
title('x input to FFT'), xlabel('n')
grid on, zoom on
Spec = fft(x);
Spectral_Mag = abs(Spec);
figure (2), clf
plot(n, Spectral_Mag,'bo','markersize',6)
title('Spectral mag'), xlabel('Freq Index (m)')
ylabel('Linear'), grid on, zoom on
Spec_Mag_Peak = Peak_Amp*N/2
```

Comment: Thanks for removing the unwanted carriage returns in my Answer Peter. I was unable to do that.

Comment: Couldn't believe the reply I got from. Must be my lucky day :P

Comment: Your book is the most essential guide to many of us. The explanations have been thought through. Only a few authors are willing (or able) to dig out what really confuses readers.